# Android: Using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK with MatOfPoint2f

Tags: java, android, opencv, opticalflow, feature-tracking

I have been unable to use calcOpticalFlowPyrLK with MatOfPoint2f. I declared my types as follows:

```
private Mat mPreviousGray;                  // previous gray-level image
private List<MatOfPoint2f> points;          // tracked features
private MatOfPoint initial;                 // initial position of tracked points
```

And use the following to find and track features
(My code is based on a sample optical flow application in C++ by Robert Laganiere.)

```
// Called whenever a new frame m is captured
private void OpticalFlow(Mat m, int maxDetectionCount, double qualityLevel,
    double minDistance) {

    if (points.get(0).total() < maxDetectionCount/2)                // Check if new points need to be added
    {
        // maxDetectionCount = 500
        // qualityLevel = 0.01
        // minDistance = 10
        Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(m, initial, maxDetectionCount, qualityLevel, minDistance);

        // add the detected features to the currently tracked features
        points.get(0).push_back(initial);
        // Have checked length of points.get(0), is not zero.
    }

    // for first image of the sequence
    if(mPreviousGray.empty())
        m.copyTo(mPreviousGray);

    if( points.get(0).total() > 0 )   // EMG - 09/22/11 - fix optical flow crashing bug 
    {       
        // 2. track features
        Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(mPreviousGray, m, // 2 consecutive images
                points.get(0), // input point position in first image
                points.get(1), // output point postion in the second image
                status,    // tracking success
                error);      // tracking error
    }

    ...

    m.copyTo(mPreviousGray);

    ...
}
```

Previously, variable `points` was of type `List<List<Point>>` and I would convert between the types by instantiating a MatOfPoint2f with `fromList` and passing that to calcOpticalFlowPyrLK.

However, I wanted to no longer do that, because this conversion from and to lists loses the correspondence between points in `initial` and `points`. I want to preserve this correspondence, so I can draw optical flow lines by iterating over the items in both matrices simultaneously.

Unfortunately, now I have the following assertion failure:

```
09-24 10:04:30.400: E/cv::error()(8216): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0) in void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, cv::Size, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double), file X:\Dev\git\opencv-2.4\modules\video\src\lkpyramid.cpp, line 593
09-24 10:04:30.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8216): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-321
09-24 10:04:30.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8216): CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: X:\Dev\git\opencv-2.4\modules\video\src\lkpyramid.cpp:593: error: (-215) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0 in function void cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, cv::Size, int, cv::TermCriteria, int, double)
09-24 10:04:30.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8216): ]
09-24 10:04:30.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8216):     at org.opencv.video.Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK_2(Native Method)
09-24 10:04:30.400: E/AndroidRuntime(8216):     at org.opencv.video.Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(Video.java:445)
```

Strangely enough, if I add this assertion myself, before calling calcOpticalFlowPyrLK, it does not fail.

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out where the real problem lies, and how I can preserve this relationship between the tracked points between frames.

**Edit**: I've discovered what needs to be done to avoid this assertion error, and the application then behaves correctly, but:

- I don't know **why**.
- I have a similar problem now for Calib3d.solvePnP, but applying convertTo to the imagePoints and objectPoints does not solve the problem here, neither with `CvType.CV_32FC2`, nor `CvType.CV_32F` or `CvType.CV_64F`

To correct the assertion failure in case of `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, I've changed `points.get(0).push_back(initial);` to the following:

```
Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(m, initial, maxDetectionCount, qualityLevel, minDistance);

MatOfPoint2f initial2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
initial.convertTo(initial2f, CvType.CV_32FC2);
// add the detected features to the currently tracked features
trackedpoints.get(0).push_back(initial2f);
```

So my question has changed to: Can someone explain the general case for me, so that I know how to solve also my problem with Calib3d.solvePnP?

Comment: If you are copying m to mPreviousGray, before optical flow, aren't they the same image instead of 2 consecutive images?

Comment: Yes, this is because the first time there is no mPreviousGray yet. On the dots ... there is another copy from m to mPreviousGray.

Comment: mMOP2fptsThisConverted = new MatOfPoint2f();
  mMOP2fptsPrevConverted = new MatOfPoint2f();
  
  mMOP2fptsPrev.convertTo(mMOP2fptsPrevConverted, CvType.CV_32FC2);
  mMOP2fptsThis.convertTo(mMOP2fptsThisConverted, CvType.CV_32FC2);
  
  Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(matOpFlowPrev, matOpFlowThis, mMOP2fptsPrevConverted,
    mMOP2fptsThisConverted, mMOBStatus, mMOFerr); i am still getting same error. anybody help on this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calcOpticalFlowPyrLK point parameters are of type MatOfPoint2f which internally is CV_32FC2.

solvePnP first parameter is **MatOfPoint3f** which internally is **CV_32FC3**. Try to convert to that to see if it fixes.

Some opencv functions are expecting specific Mat types, I guess for efficiency reasons you have to manually choose the right ones, instead of opencv guessing/converting automatically.

Answer (score 0):

someone in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346482/opencv4android-conversion-from-matofkeypoint-to-matofpoint2f) had this problem before. I recently had this problem (Assertion) in the optical flow function of OpenCV4Android. this solution only works when you could not handle previous points matrix:

instead of using convertTo() method you should put each element of Keypoint[] array you've got from matOfKeyPoints.ToArray() into the matOfPoints2f array.

the reason is explained in [this page](http://www.answers.opencv.org/question/6206/opencv4android-conversion-from-matofkeypoint-to/):

```
    KeyPoint[] arrayOfkp = keypoints.toArray();
    org.opencv.core.Point[] arrayOfp = new org.opencv.core.Point[arrayOfkp.length];
    for(int j =0;j<arrayOfkp.length;j++)
    {
        arrayOfp[j] = new org.opencv.core.Point(0, 0);
        arrayOfp[j].x = (int) arrayOfkp[j].pt.x;
        arrayOfp[j].y = (int) arrayOfkp[j].pt.y;
    }
    prevPts.fromArray(arrayOfp);
```