# cvtColor not working properly in OpenCV for Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

So I'm trying to use the `calcCopticalFlowPyrLK` method and it keeps throwing an assertion fail:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0)
```

And checkVector checks that the input Matrix is 2 channel and has a color depth of CV_32F. My input is a Mat with 4 channels and a color depth of CV_8U. When I try to convert it it fails to change every time. I used

```
Mat prevFrame; // The input Mat. Grabbed from CvCameraViewFrame. Converted to rgb

Mat prev = new Mat(rows,cols, CvType.CV_32F);
Imgproc.cvtColor(prevFrame, prev, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
prev.convertTo(prev, CvType.CV_32F);
```

But when I check the afterward prev has the correct depth (CV_32F) but only 1 element channel. I've been struggling with this for hours and I can't figure out what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

The assertion has failed on the prevPtsMat vector which is the third argument to the `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` call. It seems that the matrix you are defining here is the first argument and that should be a single channel image as it already is. 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html

I suppose you are using a points array for the third argument and you might need to explicitly create a `MatOfPoint2f()` for the points array. I think this has been described in:
[Android: Using calcOpticalFlowPyrLK with MatOfPoint2f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561292/android-using-calcopticalflowpyrlk-with-matofpoint2f)

Comment: Just saw that you posted this on Mar 20th "2013". I thought you posted this a few hours ago